# Re dimensionar Ventana

Tags: javascript, html

quiero re dimensionar la ventana del navegador, darle a un boton y que cambie el tamaño. Este es el pequeño código, algo se me escapa que no lo veo.. 
Graciass

```js
function resize( ){

 window.resizeTo(500,500)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="resize" value=" resize window" onclick="resize()">
    <script src="ejercicio4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día y bievenido a la comunidad,

Primero que nada no puedes cambiar la ventana del navegador, pero si puedes obtener las dimensiones de la pantalla, con js, para saber como está la pantalla actualmente. grande, chica, etc.

Te adjunto un script, donde puedes ver el funcionamiento

```js
go();
window.addEventListener('resize', go);

function go(){
  document.querySelector('.width').innerText = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  document.querySelector('.height').innerText = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #464646;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
}
span {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Light';
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Light';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <h1>Pantalla</h1>
  <span>Largo: <span class="width"></span></span>
  <br />
  <span>Alto: <span class="height"></span></span>
</div>
```

Saludos!